# Finding maximum numeric value in NSArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have an NSArray of NSNumbers and want to find the maximum value in the array. Is there any built in functionality for doing so? I am using iOS4 GM if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

The KVC approach looks like this:

```
int max = [[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
```

or

```
NSNumber * max = [numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
```

with numbers as an NSArray

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to use valueForKeyPath but wasn't using .intValue so it wasn't working.

Comment: What if some of items of NSArray are NSNulls? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499109/how-to-tell-nsarray-valueforkeypath-to-ignore-nsnulls

Comment: In fact, it would be better to use `@"@max.self"`.
Since `@max` uses `compare:`, it needs actual objects : with `intValue`, not only do you lose precision, but `valueForKeyPath:` has to recreate NSNumbers to work with.
As a bonus, it also works with `NSString`s or anything that implements `compare:`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *  test= @[@3, @67, @23, @67, @67];
int maximumValue = [[test valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self"] intValue];
 NSLog(@" MaximumValue = %d", maximumValue);

// Maximum = 67
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the **swift** version

```
let maxValue =  (numbers.value(forKeyPath: "@max.self") as! Double)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope will helpful to you.

```
NSArray *  arrayOfBarGraphValues = @[@65, @45, @47 ,@87 , @46, @66  ,@77  ,@47  ,@79  ,@78  ,@87  ,@78  ,@87 ];
int maxOfBarGraphValues = [[arrayOfBarGraphValues valueForKeyPath: @"@max.self"] intValue];
NSLog(@" MaximumValue Of BarGraph  = %d", maxOfBarGraphValues);
```